# SprintBoot Content-type as null

Tags: rest, spring-boot, content-type

I have a springboot application which implements a PUT method.
The client side is send the PUT request to my application but the Header "Content-type" is null... in fact, the client is not sending the "Content-type", so  SpringBoot is actually rejecting this request because it cannot handle null content-type.

```
13:24:13.658 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG vlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'null' not supported
```

Is there a way which I can make SpringBoot to accept a null Content-type and make it to assume some default content-type value?

The controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xxxx", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code=200, message="OK", response=yyyyyyyy.class)})
public ResponseEntity<?> xxxxxx(@RequestBody String s)
```

so the idea is to consume a plan text and produces as response a json object.

Comment: method must not be set to consume any specific type payload.  Try remove consume

Comment: show your controller method

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran, I have update the description with the controller method....

Comment: I had this error also, removing consume was the solution.  Why can't the error message be a litte more clear :(